# How to get rid of this white fungus

Tags: fungus

I have this fungus in my garden and it is slowly moving to my house. The picture shows it with a one Euro coin so you have an idea of the scale.
1.  Do you know what kind of fingus this is?
2.  Is it harmfull
3.  How do I get rid of it

Thanks for our help.
Erwin
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are Parasola plicatilis, the pleated inkcap. They are saprobic, meaning they live off decaying matter in the soil, and these fruiting bodies are usually short lived.  Common in grass, but whether they're moving towards your house or not, they're nothing to worry about, they're not going to damage your house. Fungal mycelium are everywhere in the soil, its chockful of it, and the only time you know it's there is when it produces such fruiting bodies in the form of mushrooms or toadstools. The vast majority of such fungal organisms are beneficial to soil and plants, with just a few exceptions (honey fungus for instance). Best not to eat any of the mushrooms though, unless you're experienced enough to recognise any edible ones that turn up -this one is considered inedible. If they don't disappear rapidly enough for your liking, just clear them away yourself.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between mushroom and toadstool? Sorry I am not native English speaker, but just curious.

Comment: @b.nota Years ago when I was a kid 'toadstool' was generally used for poisonous ones, and 'mushroom' for edible ones, but down the years, ignorance about which is which in terms of toxicity has grown, so now the two terms are virtually interchangeable. Both terms mean a fleshy, spore bearing, fungal fruiting body.